# DI doesn't inject the collection of abstract classes

Tags: java, dependency-injection, spring-boot, abstract-class, autowired

I have an abstract class

```
public abstract class SecSchema {
........
}
```

I have some child classes. I have following service with all implementations of interfaces.

```
@Service
public class SecSchemaService {

@Autowired
Collection<SecSchema> secSchemas;
....getters and setters....
}
```

When I do DI in controller:

```
    @Autowired
private SecSchemaService secSchemaService;
```

it works properly. 
However I have another abstract class:

```
public abstract class Currecny {

@Autowired
SecSchemaService secSchemaService;
...... }
```

In child class I have the following code:

```
@Component
public class USD extends Currecny implements PreValidateListener {
@PostConstruct
public void registerListeners() { secSchemaService.getSecSchemas(); }
```

I've got NullPointerException because collection

> secSchemaService.secSchemas

is null. 
I don't know why but the the collection is initialized after class USD. I tried to use annotation @Dependson but it didn't help. 
If I'd inject

```
@Autowired
Collection<SecSchema> secSchemas;
```

in class USD it works ok. So It's not working only when I'm injecting the wrapper of the collection SecSchemaService

Answer (score 0):

I've had great fun and games with post constructs trying to use other beans that haven't yet been initialised.

A guaranteed way of getting it working is to forget about post constructs and have a bean that implements ApplicationListener for ContextRefreshedEvent, and then do your final initialisation in there. You can inject any existing beans in there and do any manual wiring you want. Not ideal, but works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There was one more class child of USD and it was marked as @Component.
That was the problem. Only the last class in the hierarchy must be marked as @Component because I need only this class.